# Excel VBA: Match value in range and return value of another cell on the same row

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I have tables that look like this:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |     A      |      B      |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | $12,345.67 | ABC inc.    |
| 2 | $23,456,78 | CDE Ltd.    |
| 3 | $34,567.89 | Sample LLC  |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

I have succesfully used the following Excel formula to search for a specific dollar amount in column A and return the corresponding value from column B. For example, if $34,567.89 is found in A, the formula returns "Sample LLC":

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B3,MATCH(A3,A1:A3,0)),"")
```

The problem I have is I need to be able to run this formula in 4 worksheets simultaneously and it's not working as such. I have tried the following syntaxes to no avail:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},’Sheet1’!B1:B3,’Sheet2’!B1:B3,’Sheet3’!B1:B3,’Sheet4’!B1:B3),MATCH(A3,CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},’Sheet1’!A1:A3,’Sheet2’!A1:A3,’Sheet3’!A1:A3,’Sheet4’!A1:A3),0)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(’Sheet1’!B1:B3&’Sheet2’!B1:B3&’Sheet3’!B1:B3&’Sheet4’!B1:B3,MATCH(A3,’Sheet1’!B1:B3&’Sheet2’!B1:B3&’Sheet3’!B1:B3&’Sheet4’!B1:B3,0)),"")
```

What formula / VBA sub could I use to reach the desired result? In case anyone asks, dollar values in column A are unique (never repeated).

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B1:B3,MATCH(A3,Sheet1!A1:A3,0)),"") & 
 IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B1:B3,MATCH(A3,Sheet2!A1:A3,0)),"") &
 IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!B1:B3,MATCH(A3,Sheet3!A1:A3,0)),"") & 
 IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!B1:B3,MATCH(A3,Sheet4!A1:A3,0)),"")
```